Understanding "SP1ST" in Forward OIS ECB Quotes from ICAP
I'm currently looking at a set of forward OIS ECB dated  quotes provided by ICAP, and I came across a term that I'm not familiar with. The term is "SP1ST" as shown in the attached screenshot (eikon).

Could anyone explain what does it means in this context? Is it referring to a special period, settlement period, or something else specific to ICAP or OIS contracts?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Wild guess: spot to 1st (meeting date)

It is spot to 1st. Also known as rundown.
